# Нормальные формы (БД)

Tags: база-данных, нормализация-данных

Разбираюсь в нормализации БД, в своих таблицах в качестве первичного ключа использую поле id (а не номер паспорта, зачетки и т.д.). Во многих источниках по нормализации присутствуют такие фразы:

1. По поводу второй нормальной формы: Если у вас несоставной первичный ключ, то переходите к 3НФ ( у меня поле id по определению несоставное). Тут понятно, я просто перехожу к 3НФ.
2. По поводу третьей нормальной формы: Отношение находится в 3НФ, когда находится во 2НФ и каждый не ключевой атрибут нетранзитивно зависит от первичного ключа. Проще говоря, второе правило требует выносить все не ключевые поля, содержимое которых может относиться к нескольким записям таблицы в отдельные таблицы.

Почти везде примеры приведены с ключем, который является не "айдишником", а обычным уникальным атрибутом таблицы. Не очень понятно, как относить все эти правила к полю "id", ведь оно не ассоциируется с такими понятиями, как паспорт или номер авто и искать транзитивные зависимости затруднительно.

Comment: Искать транзитивные зависимости очень просто. Их нет. Просто по определению суррогатного ключа

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо за разъяснение! Но получается, что использование суррогатного ключа некорректно, так как по сути можно создать одну большую таблицу с таким ключем и по определению она уже будет в 3НФ? Просто если абстрагироваться от определений понятно, что такая база будет большой и тяжелой (трудно подобрать слова, но надеюсь смысл понятен).